# Setting Interval in for loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

My code deals a card to all players at once, then there is an interval before dealing again. I want to deal 3 cards to each player, 1 card at a time with interval.

```
function dealPlayers() {

  var counter = 1;

  var timer = setInterval(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < gameDB.plySeatArray.length; i++) {

      gameDB.plySeatArray[i].addCard(getNextCard(), false);

    };

    if (counter >= 3) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }

    counter++;

  }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: what/where exactly the problem is?

Comment: FWIW, you should really be separating the logic and the presentation here. The logic should happen immediately; how that is presented in the UI should be independent of this.

Comment: the problem is in the timeout. It deals the players accordingly, but does not wait before dealing each card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont really want intervals, you want a recursive function that constantly waits and deals to the next player.

```
function dealCard(playerIndex) {
    gameDB.plySeatArray[playerIndex].addCard(getNextCard(), false);
    if ((playerIndex + 1) == gameDB.plySeatArray.length) {
        //end of the queue, reset to the first player
        playerIndex = 0;
    } else {
        playerIndex++;
    }

    //Check the next playerIndex's card
    if (/*playerIndex doesnt have 3 cards, deal him in in a second*/) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            dealCard(playerIndex);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

dealCard(0);
```

Comment: Thanks tymeJV. am getting an unexpected token in line ==.  "if (/*playerIndex doesnt have 3 cards, deal him in in a second*/) { "

Comment: there can be 2 - 4 players and they can occupy any seat, leaving some vacant.

Comment: @Dayo -- Ahh didn't know about the seating, some more `if` checks can solve that! Happy to help!